# Help with understanding infinite limit of a sum.

Tags: calculus

While I was practicing some math competition problems, I came across a very interesting infinite limit problem with a summation:

$$L= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n\left(1 + \frac{k}{n} \right)^{-2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}.$$

I eventually solved it by integrating:

$$
\begin{split}
L 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{-2} \cdot \frac{1}{n}dx \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( -\frac{n}{n + x} \right) \Biggr|_0^1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{split}$$

I can't really find any answers anywhere, so my question is why does integrating work when it comes to finding the limit of a sum?

Comment: Look up Riemann-sums

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})\frac{1}{n}\equiv\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indefinite Integration is defined as a anti-derivative of a function, that is if
$$f'(x)=g(x)\ then\ \int g(x)dx=f(x)$$.
Historically the definite integration was defined as a limit of sum which was not know to be equivalent to the antiderivative. $$\int_a^bg(x)dx=h\cdot g(a)+h\cdot g(a+h)+h\cdot g(a+2h)+...h\cdot g(a+nh)\ s.t. h\to0\ and\ n\to \infty$$
This was further generalized by  Bernhard Riemann to
$$\int_a^bg(x)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty} g(x_j)(x_{n+1}-x_{n}),\ s.t\ x_n\leq x_j\leq x_{n+1},\ x_0=a,x_{\infty}=b$$.
The important [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) was discovered which proves that the definite integral is equivalent to the antidarivative(indefinite integral). This theorem allows us to solve a series using integration which you accidentally discovered. We represent the general term of the series as a function whose antidarivative is know(or can be found easily) and then calculates the sum of the series.